# Simple way to extend server disk capacities

Tags: hard-drive, storage

What's the least cumbersome way to extend existing server's storage capabilities?

I have a SuperMicro custom server and a Dell PowerEdge 2950 and I would like to extend their storage with budget hard drives, not the server ones.

I'm looking for something like a JBOD chassis (12+ 3.5") that can be connected directly to the server via some kind of controller/extension card - and then be just in /dev ready for LVM/Raid.

Comment: Is this for a long-term or short-term solution?

Comment: Long-term, but not mission critical, academic experiments on big data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there's lots of smaller enclosures about (1-5 drives) I've not seen anything big enough for 12 drives. And since you probably want the disks in caddies, I'd go with a large PC case (or 2) and several esata connectors.

A quick google turned up [this](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=serp&tok=t2woznBkuN2VAfqmR0oJ0g&pq=sata%20external%20connector&cp=10&gs_id=8cq&xhr=t&q=esata%20to%20sata&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41018144,d.ZG4&biw=960&bih=673&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=9390022988379342287&sa=X&ei=HT_1UK_mL4mFhQfYyoHICQ&sqi=2&ved=0CFUQ8wIwAg), [this](http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=CA-494-LL&tool=5) and [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-5-25in-Trayless-Mobile-3-5in/dp/B000KS8S9W/ref=sr_1_11?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1358250805&sr=1-11), if you hunt around there are probably [cheaper cases about](http://www.tweaktown.com/news/8777/sharkoon_intro_rebel12_full_tower/index.html). Or you could use a more convenitonal case and disk bay doublers [like this](http://www.scan.co.uk/products/icy-dock-mb-455spf-5x35-sata-iii-hot-swap-aluminium-backplane-into-3x525-bays). The problem with this approach is that you're going to need a cable for each HD (I believe that there are esata multiplexers availalbe - but they're very commonplace outside of dedicated enclosures).

It might be a better idea to stick in a motherboard, OS, 10Gb ethernet and hook up the drives as an [iSCSI target](http://www.zdnet.com/turn-your-linux-server-into-an-iscsi-storage-target-2039291568/) (don't route this through your existing network - use a direct connection / dedicated NIC or 2 in the server).

(NB I'm not recommending these specific products just giving you an idea of what's involved).

Comment: Thanks for idea with iSCSI, for case I'm considering something like [this](http://www.supermicro.nl/products/chassis/3U/?chs=936)
with some kind of SATA backplane conencted via some robus interface to SATA expander in the main server. Wanted to avoid buying MB/CPU/MEMORY

Comment: what is 'some robust interface'? While there are SATA cards supporting 24+ drives, they get very expensive very quickly - and they don't come with lots of external ports meaning that you start using up expansion slots for adapter plates - sata still requires one cable per disk. Find your hardware, do the sums, multiplexing across iSCSI looks a lot cheaper and less complicated to me. But if you disagree (or even if you don't) I'd be interested to see what you chose.

Comment: These links might be useful: http://www.openfiler.com http://blog.backblaze.com/2009/09/01/petabytes-on-a-budget-how-to-build-cheap-cloud-storage/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to buy a cheap NAS and to then stick the harddisks in there. Mid-range NAS devices will typically allow you to export their hard disks as iSCSI nodes, so you could then use them directly on your server. This might put quite a bit of strain on your network load, however.

Alternatively, stick in a PCI-E storage controller with external connectors in there and just hook up SATA hard disks externally.

Answer (score 0):

Server systems should not use disk storage in any non-redundant fashion - not for the OS, not for anything.

JBOD itself is a huge no-no in server environments, as it offers no redundancy whatsoever.

Instead, you could invest in a proper HBA such as a card with an LSI SAS2008 or better - this offers 2 mini-SAS 6Gbs connectors (4 lanes each), and allows you to connect 8 SAS or SATA drives directly, or one or two SAS expanders in an external chassis.

These can then be RAIDed using md or lvm2 into RAID-10 and/or RAID-6 arrays.

A basic HP SAS expander allows a further 24 or 28 drives to be connected; presumably, this will suffice for the near future.

It all depends on your requirements - OS, storage space, transfer and access speed.

Comment: Thanks, seems good. Don't worry - my terminology might be inaccurate. As I wrote in OP, I have LVM and md. JBOD was meant literally to host bunch of disks, not as logical layer.